# Variables miembro que no cambian al llamar los métodos de la clase

Tags: c++, método

Estoy comenzando a programar C++ y tengo muchos problemas al respecto. Tengo un proyecto que realizar, en el cual se trata de crear un "Juego de aventuras". Se tiene nuestro heroe y 4 monstruos.

Yo declare las siguientes clases:

- Personaje (Madre)
- Heroe     (Hija)
- Monstruo  (Hija)
- Hombre Lobo (Hija 2)
- Dragon       (Hija 2)
- Vampiro      (Hija 2)

Mi problema sucede cuando en mi clase personaje declaro una función de ataque. Cuando ejecuto el método los puntos de vida de cada jugador funcionan de manera perfecta, sin embargo cuando llamo estos valores desde el `"main.cpp"`, siempre me muestra los valores con los que fueron inicializados. He buscado por distintos lados y no he encontrado una respuesta al respecto.

Les comparto mi código:

```
int main()
{
    dragon Jose= dragon();
    ///level 1
    dragon flofy= dragon();
    Jose.attaqueentre_personnages(flofy);
}
```

`Personaje.h`

```
using namespace std;
{
    private:
        int p_vie, attaque;
        string n_caractere;

    public:
        caractere(int vie, string nom);
        int attaqueentre_personnages(caractere Personnage);
}
```

`personaje.cpp`

```
caractere::caractere(int vie, string nom)
{
    p_vie=vie;
    n_caractere=nom;
}
int caractere::attaqueentre_personnages(caractere P2)
{
    int attaque_p1;
        attaque_p1=2
        P2.Degats(attaque_p1);
        return attaque_p1;
}
```

`Monstruo.h`

```
 using namespace std;
class dragon;
class monstre: public caractere
{
  protected:
  int monstrevi;
  string monstreno;
  public: 
  monstre(int monstrev,string monstren);
};
```

`Monstruo.cpp`

```
#include "monstre.h"
#include "hero.h"

using namespace std;

monstre::monstre(int monstrev,string monstren): caractere(monstrev,monstren)
{
}
```

`Dragon.h`

```
#include "Dragon.h"

using namespace std;

dragon::dragon(): monstre(8,"Dragon")
{
}
```

`Dragon.cpp`

```
#ifndef DEF_DRAGON
#define DEF_DRAGON
#include "monstre.h"

    class dragon: public monstre
    {
      private:
        int dragonvie;
      public: 
      dragon();
    };

    #endif
```

Agradecería que me pudieran orientar al respecto :)

[image: Ejemplo del problema]

Comment: ¿Qué hace la función `Degats`?

Comment: Tropecientas líneas de código, que no sirve para nada: ni siquiera va a compilar. Quizás deverías mirar lo que es un  [mcve]. Y todo el problema es porque has declarado tus funciones-miembro para que reciban los argumentos **por copia** :-(

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por sus puntos de vista, realmente solo llevo una semana programando en c++ y si me ha costado comprender el principio de heritage. Técnicamente los cursos que he tenido se limitan a buscar información en internet y aun así nos han dejado este proyecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un lío importante en tu código, es confuso, difícil de seguir y complicado de razonar. Posiblemente sea por la inexperiencia que comentas; de ser así: no te preocupes, el tiempo lo solucionará.

---

#### Problema(s).

Para empezar, tu código, tal y como lo has compartido es imposible que compile; el archivo `Personaje.h` no tiene declaración de clase o estructura. Supongo que querías escribir esto:

```
class caractere
{
    private:
        int p_vie, attaque;
        string n_caractere;

    public:
        caractere(int vie, string nom);
        int attaqueentre_personnages(caractere Personnage);
};
```

Seguidamente, tu nomenclatura es muy confusa, en general ayuda a entender mejor el código si hay concordancia entre el nombre del archivo y su contenido, tú no sigues dicha concordancia:

- El archivo `Personaje.h` contiene la clase `caractere`.
- El archivo `Monstruo.h` contiene la clase `monstre`.

Siguiendo con la nomenclatura, ni siquiera se en qué idioma estas escribiendo, si fuese catalán *Personaje* debería ser *Personatje* y *Dragon* sería *Drac*, lo de *Caractere* no se de dónde lo sacas... es muy confuso, además de que las variables miembro tienen nombres que parecen sacados de triturar juntos los diccionarios de varios idiomas. Tampoco es habitual referirse a las clases como *Madres* e *Hijas* si no como *Base* y *Derivadas*.

Para acabar, no acabas de entender cómo funciona la herencia de objetos en C++, como analogía intenta imaginar bloques de lego:

[image]

Cada objeto es un bloque único con características únicas, cuando derivas de un bloque es como construir una figura juntando los bloques de los que ya dispones:

[image]

Una de las ventajas de la herencia es que te evita repetir código y esfuerzos. Eso es lo que te ha pasado derivando `dragon` de `monstre`, echemos un vistazo:

#### Herencia de `caractere` →  `dragon` →  `monstre`.

Vamos a echar un vistazo a tu árbol de herencia:

```
class caractere
{
    private:
        int p_vie, attaque;
        string n_caractere;

    public:
        caractere(int vie, string nom);
        int attaqueentre_personnages(caractere Personnage);
};
```

Su pieza de lego tendría este aspecto:

```
^^^^^^^^^^^ caractere ^^^^^^^^^^^
+-------+---------+-------------+
| p_vie | attaque | n_caractere |
+-------+---------+-------------+
```

De `caractere` deriva `monstre`:

```
class monstre: public caractere
{
  protected:
  int monstrevi;
  string monstreno;
  public: 
  monstre(int monstrev,string monstren);
};
```

Su pieza de lego tendría este aspecto:

```
|^^^^^^^^^^ caractere ^^^^^^^^^^|^^^^^^^ monstre ^^^^^^^|
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| p_vie | attaque | n_caractere | monstrevi | monstreno |
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

De `monstre` deriva `dragon`:

```
class dragon: public monstre
{
  private:
    int dragonvie;
  public: 
  dragon();
};
```

Su pieza de lego tendría este aspecto:

```
|^^^^^^^^^^ caractere ^^^^^^^^^^|^^^^^^^ monstre ^^^^^^^|^ dragon  ^|
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| p_vie | attaque | n_caractere | monstrevi | monstreno | dragonvie |
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Así que un `dragon` tiene como puntos de vida<sup>1</sup>:

- `p_vie` al ser `caractere`.
- `monstrevi` al ser `monstre`.
- `dragonvie` al ser `dragon`.

Por ello, cuando haces un ataque ¿qué vida le restas? ¿la de `caractere`, la de `monstre` o la de `dragon`?

#### Propuesta.

Cambia tus clases para no repetir código ni datos:

```
class caractere
{
    int p_vie, attaque;
    string n_caractere;

    friend caractere &operator >(caractere &, caractere &);

public:
    caractere(int vie, string nom);
};

class monstre: public caractere
{
    // La vida la obtiene de 'caractere'
    // El nombre lo obtiene de 'caractere'
public:
    // Llamamos al constructor Base en la Derivada
    monstre(int monstrev, string monstren) : caractere(monstrev, monstren){};
};

class dragon: public monstre
{
    // La vida la obtiene de 'monstre' que la obtiene de 'caractere'
public: 
    // Llamamos al constructor Base en la Derivada
    dragon() : monstre(1000000, "PufF, el drac màgic") {}
};
```

Para realizar el ataque entre personajes, te aconsejo usar una función externa en forma de operador, por ejemplo el operador `>` para representar que `A > B` significa `A` ataca `B`:

```
caractere &operator >(caractere &A, caractere &B)
{
    B.p_vie -= A.attaque;
    return B;
}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo de mi propuesta en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3pLuOqUMZ8qByAgr).

---

1. Adicionalmente como nombre tendría:

   - `n_caractere` al ser `caractere`.
   - `monstreno` al ser `monstre`.

Comment: Esas imágenes son de Duplo, no de Lego... Es como si dijésemos que el LEON es un AUDI cuando es un SEAT :P

Comment: @eferion Gugüel me engañó... puse "[Lego blocks](https://www.google.com/search?q=lego+blocks&tbm=isch)" y fue lo que salió :'(

Comment: Jajajajajaja, tu has jugado poco con Lego :P

Comment: @eferion Yo era más de Mecano... ♫♪♬ *Hijo de la luuuunaaaaaaaaaa* ♪♫♬

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estoy re-estructurando mis documentos. Solo llevo una semana programando y realmente me ha costado trabajo entender el principio de herencia. Me ha gustado mucho tu ejemplo.